# Spring-Boot @Async causes NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when invoker bean is instatiated from a @Configuration created bean

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-bean, clean-architecture

I am getting `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` if I add `@Async` on a method in a class annotated with `@Service`, if that class is used in another bean instantiated with `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class.

Below I sketched a simple example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class Configuration() {

    @Bean
    public A a(C c) {
        return new A(c);
    }
}

public interface B {
    public void asyncMethod();
}

public class A {

    private B b;

    public A (B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        b.asyncMethod();
    }
}

@Service
public class C implements B{

    @Async
    @Overrides
    public void asyncMethod() {
        // to stuff
    }
}
```

If I remove the `@Async` from `asyncMethod`, the application starts.
If I instantiate A by annotating it with `@Service` and `@Autowired` on the constructor, the application starts.

The constraint is that I must instantiate class `A` from a separate `@Configuration` class.

I am using a clean code architecture on the application, where classes in the core domain don't use any spring annotations on them. `A` class is part of the core domain.

I am instantiating some of these classes as Spring Beans from an outer layer so I don't "pollute" them with spring-specific annotations. `B` is part of the outer layer and can have Spring annotations.

If I put a break-point in class `B`'s constructor, I can see it is instantiated by spring just before I get: `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` for it.

I assume that the `@Async` is causing some weird behavior on the proxies. How can I approach this?

Comment: Your `@Bean` method should receive a type `B` bean not a `C`. You will get a interface based proxy and not the actual bean class. You should be programming to interfaces in the first place and you are interested in a bean of instance B and not C.

Comment: Correct, that's what it receives. I put it wrong in the example

Comment: Now your questions doesn't make sense. You are talking about *Class `B`s constructor` but that is an interface so it doesn't have a constructor. Instead of trying to obfuscate your code please post something that makes sense (and clarify your question) and at least include the full error / stack trace you get. I also guess that what is now `interface C` should actually be `interface B`?

Comment: Sorry, I messed it up. I corrected it now.

Comment: And now I'm back at my first comment... Your `@Bean` method for `A` expects a bean of type `C` which should be type `B`.

Comment: C `is a` B. I don't think this is an issue, since if I remove the `@Async` from the method spring context initializes OK.

Comment: Read my first comment again... Trust me instead of a C you need B due to that (in other words proxies).

Comment: You were right. It works now. Thanks! Submit it as an answer so I can mark it as a solution.